# Why would real_connect return null?

Tags: php, mysqli

For some weird reason, the following code is returning null, while the manual states it should either return true or false. There is also no information in the mysqli object.

**Code**

```
// Initialize MySQLi

$this->mysqli = new mysqli();

// Connect to the server

var_dump($this->mysqli);
var_dump($this->mysqli->real_connect($host, $username, $password, $database));
var_dump($this->mysqli);
```

**Output**

```
object(mysqli)#2 (17) { ["affected_rows"]=> NULL ["client_info"]=> NULL ["client_version"]=> int(50141) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> NULL ["error"]=> NULL ["field_count"]=> NULL ["host_info"]=> NULL ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> NULL ["server_info"]=> NULL ["server_version"]=> NULL ["sqlstate"]=> NULL ["protocol_version"]=> NULL ["thread_id"]=> NULL ["warning_count"]=> NULL }
NULL
object(mysqli)#2 (17) { ["affected_rows"]=> NULL ["client_info"]=> NULL ["client_version"]=> int(50141) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> NULL ["error"]=> NULL ["field_count"]=> NULL ["host_info"]=> NULL ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> NULL ["server_info"]=> NULL ["server_version"]=> NULL ["sqlstate"]=> NULL ["protocol_version"]=> NULL ["thread_id"]=> NULL ["warning_count"]=> NULL }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using it correctly.

You need to create the object using `mysqli_init()`.

Or you put the connection info in the constructor and don't call `real_connect`.

Comment: I figured this out just a minute ago. However, it's working on another machine, which is really weird. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what the context is for your code?
I just worked on a project where I set this in a config.php file..

```
<?php
$h='localhost';$u='username';$pw='PW';$db='test';
$sqli = new mysqli($h,$u,$pw,$db); ?>
```

then in a functions file this...

```
<?php
include_once 'include/config.php';
class User {
public function __construct($sqli) {
        $this->sqli=$sqli;
} //etc.
} ?>
```

The connection works well and you call your connection within
Class User functions with $this->sqli -> query("SELECT... for example.
Pass the connection when you create a user ... $user = new User($sqli);

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "context". I am kind of doing the same thing. I have one Database class, and one core file that constructs it, after which the handle gets passed around. It was (and still is) working great on another machine, but for correctness I added the initialization.